# Using math between two tables on phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, math, phpmyadmin

(please forgive me I'm new to this and I couldn't find what I was looking for)

I have two tables in my database -
Table 1: Horses(http://www.barbellsandbeakers.com/sc1.png) - lists all the information for horses in the database. Fields are HName (joined to HName in table 2), Year of Birth, Gender, LTE, Record
Table 2: Events (http://www.barbellsandbeakers.com/sc2.png) - list event results. Fields are Show Name, Date, Host, Earnings, Place, HName

I would like the following "math" to occur -
LTE = sum of "earnings" (from Events table) WHEN HName is the same
Record = number of times Place = 1 in Events table WHEN Hname is the same

Example:
Harvey has shown in 4 different shows, with earnings of $400, $200, $0 and $0. His LTE = $600. 
Harvey has shown in 4 different shows, with his place of 1, 1, 4, 6. His Record = 2.

I appreciate the help! I've joined the two tables at HName.

Edited to include screenshots of the tables

Comment: I think SUM() is what you're looking for. It's basically a JOIN (as you've done), a WHERE (where you know the conditions) and, finally, a SUM. If you're willing to share your tables, I/we might be able to help more.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I've attached screen shots of my two tables - Horses and Events.
Horses: http://www.barbellsandbeakers.com/sc1.png
Events: http://www.barbellsandbeakers.com/sc2.png

Comment: Apologies, that's not quite what I meant. I meant: upload the tables and data into something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ where I/we can play around with the queries to find the right one. (if there's a preferred SQL fiddle for stackoverflow, someone please let me know, thanks).

Comment: Something like this? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df41fe (thanks again for your patience)

Comment: I'm going to be a complete jackass and ask if you can add some data too. I want to actually run the query you request in your question.

Comment: Added some data!

Comment: I think you need to paste the new URL-- the old one still shows no data.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b00b  There you go!

Comment: I think http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/232d30/1 gets you partway there, but I'd use a temporary table instead of trying to update Results.LTE in place (minor note: you mention Events above, but I think you renamed the table Results later). I also had to change "$20,000" to "20000", so MySQL recognized it as a number.

Comment: It worked! However - it's not putting it into the table. Like, I run the query and it shows all the horses earnings, but when I go to the horse table the LTE is empty.

Comment: I think I figured it out - I used the following and it seems to be working. Thank you so much for helping!

UPDATE horses
SET horses.LTE = 
    (
SELECT 
    SUM(results.earnings) 
FROM results
    WHERE
     horses.hname=results.hname
    )